# Mongo aggregate query to get common result

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB collection with the following documents:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { "_id" : 1,"uid":"b123","name" : "test","lang" : "ja-jp"},
   { "_id" : 2,"uid":"b123","name" : "test","lang" : "en-us"},
   { "_id" : 3,"uid":"b123","name" : "demo","lang" : "ja-jp"},
   { "_id" : 4,"uid":"b123","name" : "demo","lang" : "en-us"},
   { "_id" : 5,"uid":"b456","name" : "test","lang" : "en-us"},
   { "_id" : 6,"uid":"b456","name" : "demo","lang" : "en-us"}
])
```

And want the following response

```
[{uid:"b123"}]
```

How I can get there result using Mongo aggregate query or is there any other option?

Comment: Your **`and`** is contradicting with your given document examples.

Comment: forget about and I want that reply as [{uid:"b123"}] so how I can get that?

Comment: You can use these [Logical Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) to get your result. You can use either of `find` or `aggregate` methods on the collection to perform the query.

Comment: not getting do you have any sample example for this?

Comment: Are you trying to get the first `uid`, the one that appears in the most documents, or something else?  What is the criteria you want to use to determine that "b123" is the one to return?

Comment: want those documents whose name test, demo and lang is ja-jp,en-us

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question but here are several things you may do to have the uid field returned:

1. Using find and project:

```
db.inventory.find({
  uid: 'b123'
}).project({
  uid: $uid
});
```

This will result in a list of `{uid: 'b123'}`.
If you want only unique result you may use aggregate with `$group` as follow:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      uid: 'b123'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        uid: '$uid'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      result: {
        $addToSet: '$_id'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Note that the second `$group` purpose is to collect them all under one array.
The response will be something like that:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  result: [
    {uid: 'b123'}
  ]
}
```

Hope that's answers your question